# Tree with radius and diameter

Tags: graph-theory

**How to show that a radius in a tree is not necessarily half its diameter ??**

I'm using the following relation to prove but cannot find proper explanation

2*radius-1 ≤ diameter ≤ 2*radius

Suggest if there is any other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Every [path graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) is a tree.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a tree with only $2$ vertices. Then the minimum eccentricity of a vertex (the maximum distance from that vertex to any other), the radius, is $1$. The *maximum* distance between two vertices, the diameter, is also $1$.